# Does there exist an initial condition to make this sequence integer?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am interested if the following is true:

Given a natural number $N$, and $\omega_1, \omega_2 >0$ real numbers,  does there exist a $k_0$such that $k_0,k_1,\dots, k_N$ defined by
$$ k_n = (k_0 - \tfrac12 ) \left( \dfrac{1+ \omega_2}{1+\omega_1} \right)^n + \frac12$$
are all integers?

I think this is a number theory related problem which is not my strong suit, but I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Are the two omegas real numbers?

Comment: @peter.petrov yes.

Comment: It is very unlikely and depends of course of $Omega$

Answer (score 1):

$$2k_n-1=(2k_0-1) \left(\frac{1+\omega_2}{1+\omega_1}\right)^n$$

Therefore $\frac{1+\omega_2}{1+\omega_1}$ is rational. Let $\frac{1+\omega_2}{1+\omega_1} = \frac ab$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $b^n | (2k_0-1), n\le N$ so $b$ must be odd, and we can have $k_0=(1+b^N)/2$. Now
$$2k_n-1=b^{N-n} a^n$$

so $a$ must be odd too, and if $a$ is odd then $k_n$ is an integer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you. I just updated my answer.